# Text loading in UILabel is slowing down UITableView scroll

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a jerky scroll down issue because of this line:

```
NSString *text =[NSString stringWithCString:[[Text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The text length differs from cell row to cell row. I have this line at:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue? Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the line you provided is slowing down the scroll ? Provide the whole cellForRow.. method

Comment: I am sure because i comment it out and scroll becomes smooth...cellForRowAtIndexPath: has too many lines to post it here it will confuse you!

Comment: By the way do you know that stringWithCString is deprecated long time ago? You should not use it..may be this is the problem....

Comment: from where  are you adding getting the string ?

Comment: hmmmm did not know that! I will check to load the NSString without it.

Comment: just check with some hardcoded value for the string

Comment: Nop its not stringWithCString the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i was searching on my issue for quite a few hours and i have found that i had to precompute all my uitableviewcells and save them into an nsmutablearray. I had to precompute height of its cell also because the height is dynamic not static. After doing all the computation i had to add this line to the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
             return [self.CellObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //this just loads the precomputed cell
}
```

and also i had to add the height of each cell like this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

  NSNumber *height=[HeightObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height1=[height floatValue];
    return height1;

}
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Load the text asynchronously to the table view cell like:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *objects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    CustomCell *cell=[objects objectAtIndex:0];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *text =[NSString stringWithCString:[[Text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
              // set the string to cell here using cell object.

            });
        });


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: even doing your suggestion it is Jerky! it seems that the SetText: of UILabel does a lot of time to show the text...any other thoughts? If i make the text smaller then there is no jerky scrolling...

Comment: The cell is custom with 5 objects on it and one of them is an uilabel . I use UIlabel setText: ...

Comment: actually it should not take much time to set on UILabel if your array is already loaded.above code worked for me when i load images asynchronously from the url . From where are you getting those elements inside the Text array.

Comment: WHat do you mean already loaded? Text is loaded in the array previously. I use addObject to add the NSString to the array previously. I do not know what is wrong either! I get the elements from a database query then i load each one in the NSMutableArray and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath i load each one to each UILabel using array objectAtIndex:

Comment: I used NSCache to see if it helps loading the cell faster but still i get the jerky scroll! Any help appreciated!